# Pavuk downloader destroys images from certain server

Tags: html, linux, wget, pavuk

I use [`pavuk`](http://www.pavuk.org/) to grab websites. However, the images downloaded by pavuk from one particular server are corrupt! It seems they are several bytes short:

```
/usr/bin/pavuk http://files.zemedelska-krajina.cz/200000061-0970a0a6ab/50000000.jpg
```

the output is

```
URL[ 1]:     1(0) of     1  http://files.zemedelska-krajina.cz/200000061-0970a0a6ab/50000000.jpg
Starting time :  19:14:20
S:  31256 B [R: 617.0 kB/s] [ET: 0:00:00]
Received Encoded file but decoding not allowed (untouched)
Ending time :    19:14:20
download: OK
```

The image downloaded by pavuk has only `31256` bytes, while the original image has `31331` bytes! Where is the problem?

The key probably lies in the message **"Received Encoded file but decoding not allowed"**. Not sure what that means, but even adding the `-Enc` option doesn't solve the problem.

I use pavuk-0.9.35 on Debian 7 (wheezy). I will appreciate your advice.

Comment: Maybe the server claims to gzip the image, but in fact it doesn't.  Have you tried -noEnc?

Comment: You are right @James! The image is gzip compressed! The `-noEnc` helped!

Comment: Oh no @James, `-noEnc` works just with the downloading of the single image, but will break when downloading the whole website...

Comment: In the [docs for Pavuk](http://www.pavuk.org/man.html) under the details for -noEnc/-Enc (search for it) it talks about broken servers.  I believe you are dealing with such a server.  You will probably have to selectively enable -noEnc only for certain problematic images or resources.

Comment: @James this can be done? How can you apply `-noEnc` only to some of the files?

Comment: I wish I had a good answer for you.  Maybe you can figure out how to download everything except images, and then do a second pass using -noEnc where you only download images.